# Choosing between Python HTTP clients urllib3 and requests

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib3

Python's built-in HTTP clients don't have many features, so even the Python docs recommend using requests. But there's also urllib3, which requests, itself uses, and they share some core developers, making me think they're more complementary than competing.

When would I use urllib3 instead of requests? What features does requests add on top of urllib3?

Comment: To oversimplify things: `requests` is syntax sugar, `urllib3` does all the heavy lifting underneath.

Answer (score 0):

Requests was conducted on the basis of urlib3 encapsulation.
Since Requests are already an encapsulated library, many functions can be simplified. For example: timeout setting, proxy setting, file upload, get cookies, etc.
However,requests can only be used directly and cannot be invoked asynchronously, so requests are slow.
So, if you're writing small spiders that don't require much speed, consider using requests.